# Object in center back of Volvo 850 engine compartment

Tags: engine, volvo

What is the object attached to the center back of the engine compartment of a 1996 Volvo 850 as circled in red in the photo below:

[image: volvo 850 engine compartment]

Comment: Do you have a better picture? This is too grainy to get a detailed look. Also, what Volvo model is this?

Comment: I see it in the engine compartment of both the 850 wagon and in the V70. Both of those had the T5 engine, I believe (which this is, right)? I don't see what it is connected to directly, but looks as though a vacuum line is attached somehow. Not sure what it is, though.

Comment: In some of the pictures I have seen, it looks as though it has a slit loom with an electrical connector at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [video](https://youtu.be/HsHNSBT6vqo) it is the horn for the alarm system. It is separate from the horns mounted by the radiator.

And eEuroparts.com shows the item as [**Volvo Alarm Horn - Genuine Volvo 30796932**](https://www.eeuroparts.com/Parts/75070/Alarm-Horn-30796932/)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a horn to me, but hard to tell from the low-res photo.
[image]

Does it have electrical or vacuum connections going into it?